# Boostrap 3 -4 active class link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

This is my code using Bootstrap 3 and it gives me a list of pages along bottom of the page horizontal, however when I upograde to Boostrap 4 the list is vertical now? I need it to be Horizontal any idea how?

```
<?php

$number_list = array();
for($i =1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    if($i == $page) {
        echo "<li '><a class='page-link' href='index.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";
    }  else {
        echo "<li '><a href='index.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";
    } 
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Your PHP is irrelevant, the HTML it generates is not. The CSS you use is rather important.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is a major release, and it is not fully backward compatible with version 3. Your question is not related to php, it is related to css

Answer (score -2):

Try using some CSS something like this. The float left of the `li` will place them horizontally, next to each other, the overflow rule for the `ul` makes sure all content is held inside the `ul` and doesn't spill over.

```
ul#name-of-ul {
    overflow: auto;
}

ul#name-of-ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

If they still don't look horizontal, try adding a `width` rule to the `li`.